# How filter by a field with a join on two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

how the filter the query  i'm need filter by nombre i need a query.

query = select  userstats.email as email, count(intento) as Attempts, user.accesses as Accesses from userstats inner join user on user.email = userstats.email group by Email;

```
+---------------------------+----------+--------+
| email                     | Attemps  |accesses|
+---------------------------+----------+--------+
| felixcriv@gmail.com       |       84 |     29 |
| felixcriv@me.com          |        1 |      0 |
| geronimo_76@hotmail.com   |        1 |      0 |
| gramirezcarrero@gmail.com |      128 |     90 |
+---------------------------+----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the first table.

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| email       | varchar(55) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| names       | varchar(60) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| password    | text        | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| privileges  | int(11)     | YES  |     | 2                 |                             |
| accesses    | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| last_access | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| logged      | int(11)     | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
| ip_machine  | varchar(35) | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| session_id  | text        | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| platform    | text        | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| status      | int(11)     | YES  |     | 0                 |                             |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

the second table.

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| iduserStats | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| ip_machine  | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| email       | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| intento     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| logged      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| fechaHora   | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

i need draw a table similar:

```
+---------------------------+----------+--------+
    | nombres                   | intentos |logeos |
    +---------------------------+----------+--------+
    | name                      |       84 |     29 |
    | name2                     |        1 |      0 |
    | name3                     |        1 |      0 |
    | name4                     |      128 |     90 |
    +---------------------------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Can't you modify query to return name instead of email ? Like this:

select userstats.names as name, count(intento) as Attempts, user.accesses as Accesses from userstats inner join user on user.email = userstats.email group by Email;

Comment: @Dmitriy Reznik :- voted up cause I also Told the same... :)
but you forget to put **name** in **group by** clause..

Comment: @pratikgarg: If `Email` is a primary key, you don't have to put `user.name` in `GROUP BY` in MySQL. But if you want to follow standards, you should add `user.accesses` as well as `user.name`.

Comment: is it possible to select non group by column in a statement having group by clause, in mysql?.. as of now I am working in oracle database system .. and in Oracle you can not do like this ..

Comment: @pratikgarg: Yes, it is possible, albeit the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html "GROUP BY and HAVING with Hidden Columns (MySQL)") recommends doing it with caution.

Comment: Then I have one more doubt.. @AndriyM you only can tell me about this... 
please take an example where distinct values for name is present for a given Email.. it is possible .. then how query will give output.. whether it will give multiple row for email and name value combination .. or will it give single record with any one of name value .. or it will simply concatenate the name value and then give as a value for name in this sql .?

Comment: @pratikgarg: `Email` is actually the primary key, as per the OP's schema. Therefore, you can't have multiple names per email, as all emails will be unique. This is actually one case where reducing GROUP BY to just a PK column makes sense, since other columns from the same table as the specified PK can always be determined by the said PK. In all or most other cases they aren't, and they are fetched randomly if they are neither aggregated nor included in GROUP BY. The linked article elaborates more on this.

Answer (score 1):

then you can try-

```
    select names , --userstats.email as email, 
          count(intento) as Attempts, 
          user.accesses as Accesses 
     from userstats inner join user 
       on user.email = userstats.email 
  group by Email, names
```

Comment: and for consult the email     select names , --userstats.email as email, 
          count(intento) as Attempts, 
          user.accesses as Accesses 
     from userstats inner join user 
       on user.email = userstats.email where user.email like 'name@gmail.com';